# heroku reivew app creation is borken - app.json invalid

Tags: heroku

Creation of review apps in heroku pipeline is broken. The only error message I get is `app.json invalid`. There aren't any logs, which doesn't help debugging or further investigation.

I came across [app.json](https://github.com/app-json/app.json), but app.json validated all right.

Any thoughts on how I could fix it or investigate further?

Answer (score 3):

We got got a response from heroku support.

The specific problem, in our case, was that we had specified an environment variable as a required configuration variable in our app.json's env section, but had recently deleted that variable from the parent app variable set.

So we just removed that from the app.json file.

Answer (score 0):

I also checked to make sure the format of app.json was in UTF-8 format.  It had been in UTF-16 format. Upon changing to UTF-8, the invalid format error message went away when (re)building the Review App.